# alias analysis vs. pointer analysis vs. points-to analysis

Tags: code-analysis, static-analysis

Currently I am reading a lot about static code analysis. There are several terms that confuses me because I can't really tell what the difference is.

- alias analysis
- pointer analysis
- points-to analysis

What is the difference (if any) between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Pointer analysis` or `points-to analysis` is a static program analysis that
determines information on the values of pointer variables or expressions.

Although the literature is not entirely consistent on terminology, `pointer analysis`
is a near-synonym of `alias analysis`. 
Whereas, however, `pointer/points-to analysis` typically tries to model heap objects and asks *“what objects
can a variable point to?”*, `alias analysis` algorithms focus on the question of *“can a pair of variables/expressions point to the same object (aliases) ?”*

Comment: Just thought I would link [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aldrich/courses/15-819O-13sp/resources/pointer.pdf) here: "Two common kinds of pointer analysis are alias analysis and points-to analysis. Alias analysis computes a set S holding pairs of variables (p,q), where p and q may (or must) point to the same location. On the other hand, points-to analysis, as described above, computes a relation points-to (p,x) where p may (or must) point to the location of the variable x.